# OpenCV: Feature Matching + Homography Help to tune results

Tags: opencv, feature-detection

I am looking for some help in fine tuning the results of using Feature Matching and Homography, [as described in this tutorial.](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html)

I am trying to use the approach described in the article to crop and deskew  faxed/scanned forms, as a preprocessing step for identifying fields for sending to an OCR process. This works REALLY well for about 90% of the test scans, but for the rest it fails in a way that makes the results unusable.

When it fails it seems like all of the features of the source image are matched to a single point on the test image: [image: Image of feature matching failing]

I am probably out of my depth on this problem, so any direction on addressing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can match in both directions and only accept answer where both directions show the same match. After matching you can compare the best and the second best match and only accept answers where the best match is significantly better than the first one.

Comment: maybe try using a different detector/descriptor. orb gives pretty good results (and helps you avoid the patent issues of using sift). Also as stated by @Micka, validate your matches in both directions